# Trying to simplify a logarithmic exponent

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I am solving a recurrence and ended up with `n^(lgk/lgn)`, where `lg` is in base 2. Can we simplify `n^(lgk/lgn)` even further? I really cannot see it !!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Since
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\log_b(x)}{\log_b(y)}=\log_y(x)
> \end{align*}
>
> we get
>   \begin{align*}
> n^{\frac{\log_2(k)}{\log_2(n)}}=n^{\log_n(k)}=k
> \end{align*}